# Regex to get last 4 characters before first occurrence of "/"

Tags: c#, regex

Below are the test input . The result I want is `AAA-` and `AB--` respectively. The input string has no specific pattern. So first occurrence of `/` and the 4 character before that is the result I want to have.

```
Test line abc (r);AAA-/2010/001
Test line abc (r);AB--/2010/001
```

Comment: First and foremost, you should provide the code you have problem with. Next, why regex?

Comment: [String.indexOf(char)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx) then you want to [String.Substring(int, int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) it?

Comment: I want to use regex not c# code because I need to place this regex in SQL  statement as well . If it is just C# then it easy .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like that? (EDIT: in .NET regex patterns, `/` does not need escaping)

```
(.{4})/
```

Consider sites like https://regex101.com for future needs)

Comment: I would not recommend regex101.com for testing .NET regexes as it does not support their syntax. It can be used, yes, but only when "you know what you are doing". Here, a ``\`` is redundant in ``\/``.

Comment: @stribizhev Oh, thanks. But still, this site is pretty awesome at stage when you absolutely don't know what one regex is doing)

Comment: Yes, however, to test .NET regex, you can use a free tool called [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm), it is also a very nice tool for understanding what is going on with your regex. At regex101.com, you cannot test patterns like `(?<!http://[^/]+)some_string` while they are valid .NET regex patterns. Also, [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) is good for online regex testing. [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) is great for testing regex performance.